# User profile_image dimensions

Tags: support

I'd like to use the user `profile_image` `string` property (which is the url of a user's avatar image e.g. http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fbc10e7e541ba1f171a06af062bef7c0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) and wondered if there's any documentation about the dimensions of the avatars. I have searched both, Gravatar specs, and the stack exchange api documentation but can't find any reference.

Are all `profile_image`s on Gravatar? And are they all the same dimensions? The few I've looked at all seem to be 80 x 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profile_image` can be any size, it's a consumers responsibility to resize it.

Typically they'll be 128x128, but that's not contractual.  This is a consequence of Facebook sourced profile images, [like this user](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/21062?site=stackoverflow), whose `profile_image` is 180x180.

Not that the images being square is not guaranteed either, for the same reasons.